# How to select from nested json array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a JSON I get from API as :

```
 $scope.data = [{
        "primary": "white",
        "sub": ["white 1", "white 2", "white 3"]

    },{
        "primary": "black",
       "sub": ["black 1", "black 2", "black 3"]

    }];
```

I want to group by primary and selectable values are Array sub

like:

```
**White**
   white 1
   white 2
   white 3
**Black**
   Black 1
   Black 2
   Black 3
```

I am able to group by primary key but I cannot get inner values. Here's what I have:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select
        ng-model="myOption"
        ng-options="val.primary group by value.primary for value in data">

    </select>
    <div>
        ng-model value: {{myOption}}
    </div>
</div>
```

(here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm6of9bu/648/)

Comment: What do you want to write into model when item is selected?

Comment: need to map data to one array...and use group by

Comment: Could you provide final JSON you want to get.

Comment: @c-smile OP is trying to populate a `<select>` not get json

Comment: @charlietfl then he/she shall provide html structure that is needed at the end. E.g. are `<optgroup>`s needed, etc.

Comment: @c-smile  <optgroup> seems obvious to me, as well as answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve this with little tweak:

Here is what I have tried

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="myOption" ng-options="value.sub group by value.primary for value in data2">
```

And I flattened my nested JSON as :

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
   datas = [{
        "primary": "white",
        "sub": ["white 1", "white 2", "white 3"]

    },{
        "primary": "black",
       "sub": ["black 1", "black 2", "black 3"]
    }];
   $scope.data2 = [];
   datas.forEach(function(entry){
     entry.sub.forEach(function(sub){
        $scope.data2.push({primary:entry.primary,sub:sub})
    });
 });
};
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jm6of9bu/658/

Answer (score 3):

You need to flatten your array. Even with `group by`, `ng-options` works on a flat array:

```
$scope.data2 = [
    {primary: "white", sub: "white1"},
    {primary: "white", sub: "white2"},
    {primary: "white", sub: "white3"},
    {primary: "black", sub: "black1"},
    {primary: "black", sub: "black2"},
    {primary: "black", sub: "black3"},
    ];
```

Then you could do:

```
<select
    ng-model="myOption"
    ng-options="value as value.sub group by value.primary for value in data2">

</select>
```

The model will be set to the `value` object - e.g. `{primary: "white", sub: "white2"}`. If you want to set it to `"white2"`, `"black3"`, etc... then use:

```
ng-options="value.sub as value.sub group by value.primary for value in data2"
```

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle for this answer I was working on as @New Dev came up with the same.  http://jsfiddle.net/jm6of9bu/653/

Comment: This is okay but is there any way i can iterate without flattening array, because I am getting JSON from API

Comment: You'd need to set up a function to translate it between interactions.

Comment: @ShankarRegmi, The input expression must result in a flat array. You *could* do `"... value in flatten(data)"`, but I'd recommend against that, since this "flattening" is a heavy operation that would happen on every digest cycle. Instead, flatten once in the controller, and convert the selected object to the right form via `ng-change`

Comment: then how can I know which sub data from which primary was selected @tPlummer

Comment: @ShankarRegmi, how should your selected model value look like?

Comment: How do you flatten my array into yours? @NewDev

Comment: @shankarregmi, make a double loop and push each inner element into a new array

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { 

$scope.data = [{
        "primary": "white",
        "sub": ["white 1", "white 2", "white 3"]

    },{
        "primary": "black",
       "sub": ["black 1", "black 2", "black 3"]

    }];


$scope.dataList=[];
$scope.data.forEach(function(value,index){
    value.sub.forEach(function(temp,index){    
    $scope.dataList.push({
      'groupType':value.primary,
      'value':temp
      });
    });    
});
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select
        ng-model="myOption"
        ng-options="data.value as data.value group by data.groupType for data in dataList">

    </select>
    <div>
        ng-model value: {{myOption}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

I might not fully understand what it is you're wanting but

If you're wanting the sub values to display change the val.primary to val.sub before the grouping

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select
        ng-model="myOption"
        ng-options="val.sub group by value.primary for value in datas">

    </select>
    <div>
        ng-model value: {{myOption}}
    </div>
</div>
```